# sdb path - Storage Inspector Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, local-storage, inspector

I`m using Android Studio to develop a Flutter App with a drift database.
For inspection i like to use the local storage inspection tool.
What is the sdb path and the idevice path, when use emulator.

[image: 1]

I've tried to search after something like the sdb.exe but didnt found something